# Number of Tall Integers

Tags: combinatorics

Call a positive six-digit integer *tall* if, upon removing any number of digits (not necessarily consecutive) from the number, the number, when read left-to-right, is always composite. How many such six-digit *tall* integers are there?

Note: Only the numbers 4, 6, 8, and 9 can used, but this gets frustrating as primes such as 449 and 499 appear. I am not sure how to deal with the prime number stemming from the 9's.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. You will that questions without attempted solutions or additional thoughts are generally not well received here. Please add your thoughts and/or attempt at finding a solution yourself.

Comment: Why the restriction to $\{4,6,8,9\}$?

Comment: @EricSnyder The restriction is because if any digit in the number is prime, the number can be stripped of every digit besides that prime number, and this would invalidate that number. Therefore, a _tall_ integer must only consist of composite digits. Zero, along with one, is neither prime nor composite, while two, three, five, and seven are all prime. This means that _tall_ integers can only be formed from {4,6,8,9}.

Comment: So clearly before a $9$ you cannot have any $8$, nor two $4$s, and nothing but $6$s before any two $9$s. What other restrictions can you find?

Comment: I got $1593$ with a brute-force calculation (checking all $\{4,6,8,9\}$-sequences of length $6$ that don't have any of `89, 449, 499, 6469, 6949, 9649, 9949, 666649, 946669` as a subsequence.

Comment: @ploosu2 Do you know if there is a way to do this by hand, without using excruciating casework?

Comment: @AveryWenger Sorry, no. Maybe if given those primes (finding them by hand seems impossible(?)) some sort of inclusion-exclusion but that looks like big work too.

Comment: Or you could build a state machine that has as states all the possible suffixes of those forbidden primes but there are so many it's not really feasible by hand. EDIT: On a second thought, wouldn't you also need to have subsets of them, because you need to keep track if on a next symbol you could get many of them...

Comment: An easy lower bound is $792$. All combinations with the even digits work ($3^6=729$) and so do all combinations consisting of sixes and nines ($2^6=64$). One is subtracted from the sum due to double counting $666666$.

Answer (score 1):

It can be split to two cases: those numbers that have an $8$ and those that don't. Further, split the $8$-case by where the first $8$ appears: let the number be (as string) $u8v$ where $u$ is a $\{4,6,9\}$-word of length $k$ and $v$ a word of length $6-1-k$. Notice that $v$ can't have a $9$ and as $u$ is tall, this means that $v$ can be any word of the alphabet $\{4,6,8\}$ (all the primes we need to forbid end in $9$ so the subsequence can't end on $v$).

So, if we denote by $f_k$ the number of tall $\{4,6,9\}$-words of length $k$, the number of tall words of length 6 is equal to

$$f_6 + \sum_{k=0}^5 f_k3^{5-k}$$

I still calculated these by brute-force:

$$
315 + 
1 \times 3^5 + 3 \times 3^4 + 9 \times 3^3 + 25 \times 3^2 + 61 \times 3 + 141 \times  1 = 1593
$$

**EDIT:**
Further we can split the count of $f_k$ by the appearance of last $9$. Remove $9$ from the end of the primes and forget the two of length 6 since those are just full numbers and we can subtract 2 in the end.

So if we let $g_m$ be the number of $\{4,6,9\}$-words of length $m$ that **has a subsequence** among $\{ 44, 49, 646, 694, 964, 994 \}$ (that is we're counting the complement). We have

$$f_k = 3^k - 2\delta_{k=6} - \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} g_m 2^{k-1-m}$$

**EDIT2:**
Yes, I think I cracked it: $g_m = 3^m - (2^m + 3)$, because the sequences not having any of $\{ 44, 49, 646, 694, 964, 994 \}$ as subsequences are (using regular expressions) $\{ 6, 9\}^* \cup 46* \cup 6*4 \cup 946*$. This when assuming $m>2$, the first ones are easy to see: $g_0 = g_1 = 0$, $g_2 = 2$.

All in all, we get the answer is

$$
3^6-2-\sum_{m=2}^5 (3^m-2^m-3)2^{5-m} + \sum_{k=0}^5 \left (  3^k - \sum_{m=2}^{k-1} (3^m-2^m-3)2^{k-1-m} \right)3^{5-k} \\
= 3^6 + 7\times 3^5 - 2 - \sum_{m=2}^5 (3^m-2^m-3)2^{5-m} - \sum_{k=0}^5\sum_{m=2}^{k-1} (3^m-2^m-3)2^{k-1-m} \\
\dots \\
= 1593
$$

Comment: It's still brute-force, but at least it's $3^6$ (or more like $\frac{3^7-1}{2}$ as you need to do $f_1,\dots, f_6$) rather than $4^6$.

Comment: Some ideas for $g_m$: if a 4 comes then only allowed is 6 (but not in the case that has seen a 6 before the 4). And musn't have seen any of 69, 96 or 99 before the 4. So are the only allowable just 2, 6, 9, 94, 6*4, 46*

Comment: Is this final approach still using brute force? Also, can you explain it a bit more please?

Comment: @AveryWenger Now it's brute force only for getting the list of primes to avoid (i.e. `89, 449, 499, 6469, 6949, 9649, 9949, 666649, 946669`). What parts need more clarification? **1.** Splitting by appearance of first $8$. **2.** Splitting by appearance of last $9$. **3.** "Seeing" the count $g_m$. I know the end is a bit sketchy. But start by thinking that if there's a $4$ what can come after it? Only $6$'s. And before? Possibly any positive amount of $6$'s (and then nothing after) or one $9$ (and then any amount of $6$'s after).

Comment: And I forgot to mention (if it isn't obvious) that the list of primes to avoid comes by taking all primes ($<10^6$) having just the digits we're using and further filtering out the ones that have another prime in the list as a subsequence. In another words we're taking the minimal elements in the partial order "has as a subsequence".

Comment: OK, thanks. Luckily the brute force for the primes is not really that bad cause there are not many numbers we have to even check.

Answer (score 0):

So the rules are:

- The only single digit tall numbers are $4,6,8,9$.
- Any number obtained by removing digits from a tall number is also tall.
- Any number consisting of a tall number followed by a string of digits from $4, 6, 8$ is tall. (If after a removal, any of these digits remain, then the number will be even, and thus composite. If they are all removed, the number can be obtained from removing digits from the original tall number, and thus must be tall.)

Thus it is sufficient to examine which tall numbers can end in a $9$. Call them "tall-9". For tall-9 numbers, we have the additionals rules:

- There can be no $8$ digits. (Otherwise the prime $89$ could be formed.)
- There can be at most one $4$. (Otherwise the prime $449$ could be formed.)
- Only $6$s can occur between the $4$ and the ending $9$. (Otherwise the prime $499$ could be formed.)
- Any number with only $6$ and $9$ for digits is tall. (All such numbers are divisible by $3$, and removing digits just results in another number of the same form.)

Thus it remains to examine numbers with leading $6$ and $9$ digits, one $4$, more $6$s, and a final $9$. Of these,

- $4$ followed by any number of $6$s and a final $9$, is always a tall number. The full number is divisible by $7$ (to get the quotient, just remove the leading $4$ and change the $9$ to $7$), and any removals either leave another number of the same kind, or a number with just $6, 9$ digits, or a number with just $4, 6$ digits, all of which are composite.

I haven't spotted any similar rules for such numbers with $6$ and $9$ digits to the left of the $4$, but even if it must be done by brute force, this is a much more limited set to test. Note that you will want to check all possibilities with six or fewer digits, since the latter can be expanded to six digit tall numbers, by adding $4,6,8$ on the right.